# Any specific word to describe a date, contains only year, month and day, but not time?

Tags: time, dates

I want a word to describe the name of a date, that is a date only contains year, month and day, like "2017-7-1", but not contains time "12:05".

The word "date" is not specific, because it can also contains time.

Comment: The specific word for a single specification of a day month and year, like "25 July 2017" is ***date.*** Please edit your question to describe in more detail what you refer to in the title.

Comment: To avoid having your question downvoted, put on hold, or closed, make sure to follow the guidelines for asking questions. Please see: [Help Center > Asking](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking), and in particular, [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: "Date" is pretty  commonly accepted to mean just the date. "Date and time" would also include time.

Comment: @MarkDWorthenPsyD Hi, I have edit the question, try to make it specific enough.

Comment: I agree with @RoryAlsop  :O)

Comment: the reason types like [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) exist spelled and described like they are: *(Represents an instant in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day.)* is because ’date’ does not include the time of day.

Answer (score 3):

**Calendar date.**  This is the term used in commodity trading, where the [CME Group's online glossary](https://institute.cmegroup.com/support/glossary) is very helpful (look under "D").

In trading, orders are executed while the market is open, but many activities, such as settlement or margin calculation, take place at the end of the day.  There is a need to define dates and times in a rigorous but understandable way.