# Term for a specific Month and Year in time

Tags: dates

Similar to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/402759/any-specific-word-to-describe-a-date-contains-only-year-month-and-day-but-not), is there a term to describe a month and year in time, without the day of the month?

eg. a term for the month of `May, 2018` as opposed to `23rd May, 2018`.

Comment: What’s wrong with ‘the month”? The NBER treats months as points in time when considering peaks and lows in economic activity.

Comment: I too am confused why *month* is not enough.

Comment: The word 'month' is being used specifically for calendar month (eg. May, September) in the same context